# running an asyncio using executors raises an error of my return type not being callable

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

in the code below, i am trying to find all query all the files that contain the extension '.py'
I do a breadth first search on the list of directories in my path and recursively call the same function on the resulting list of subdirectories. i get an error saying

```
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=TypeError("'generator' object is not callable")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

the code is given below

```
from pathlib import Path
from os.path import sep as pathsep
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(4)

async def main(basedir, query):
    loop.run_in_executor(None, find_files(basedir, query) )

@asyncio.coroutine
def find_files(path, query_string):
    subdirs = []
    for p in path.iterdir():
            fullpath = str(p.absolute)
            if p.is_dir and not p.is_symlink():
                subdirs.append(p)
            if query_string in fullpath:
                print(fullpath)
    loop =  asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = [loop.run_in_executor(executor, find_files, subdir, query_string) for subdir in subdirs] # this doesnt work
    yield from asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return subdirs


query = '.py'
basedir = Path(pathsep).absolute() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.set_default_executor(executor)
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main(basedir, query))
    finally:
        loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
        executor.shutdown(wait = True)
        loop.close()
```

'''

EDIT: I realize the errors from user4815162342 answer below, this works now

```
import asyncio
from pathlib import Path
from os.path import sep as pathsep
from collections import deque
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor

query = '.py'
basedir = Path(pathsep).absolute() 
futures = deque()

def find_files(path, query_string):
    subdirs = []
    try:
        for p in path.iterdir():
                fullpath = str(p.absolute)
                if p.is_dir and not p.is_symlink():
                    subdirs.append(p)
                if query_string in fullpath:
                    print(fullpath)
    return subdirs

async def main(executor):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = [loop.run_in_executor(executor, find_files, basedir, query) ]
    completed, _ = await asyncio.wait(task)
    result = [t.result() for t in completed]
    futures.append(result[0])
    while futures:
        future = futures.popleft()
        for subdir in future:
            task = [loop.run_in_executor(executor, find_files, subdir, query) ]
            completed, _ = await asyncio.wait(task)
            result = [t.result() for t in completed][0]
            futures.append(task[0].result() )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tstart = time.time()
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(
        max_workers=4,
    )

    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        event_loop.run_until_complete(
            main(executor)
        )
    finally:
        event_loop.close()    
print('time elapsed is', time.time() - tstart)
```

Comment: You don't need `asyncio.wait()` to await a single task! Instead of the whole ceremony of calling `asyncio.wait([...])` and then extracting the result list, you could just have `actual_result = await loop.run_in_executor(...)`. That's what `await` is **for**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

- First, `run_in_executor` expects a callable object, which it will invoke in a different thread, suspend the execution of the current coroutine, and resume it once the callable has returned a value or raised an exception. In other words, `run_in_executor` expects a **function** and you are giving it a coroutine object instead, which is why you get an exception that such object is not callable.
- Second, you should **await** the result of `run_in_executor`. The lack of `await` is the reason you are warned that the exception is never retrieved.
- Finally, the function you are invoking is already a coroutine, so you don't need `run_in_executor` in the first place. `run_in_executor` is only for invoking CPU-bound or legacy blocking code. Just await it directly: `await find_files(...)`.

Please also note that you should be using `async def` and `await` in preference to the `asyncio.coroutine` decorator and `yield from`. The latter is deprecated and will be removed soon.

Comment: This is actually a really good answer. It helped me a lot, thanks! :)